# binary search textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a textbox which i need to type in a file name, but the file name doesnt have to be the whole file name only partial.

For Example

iexplorere.exe which would be stored in a list box. Then all i would have to type woule be "iexpl" and then the results would be in a message box with full file name.

Im having trouble with the binary search method.

My code so far is:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


        fValue = bList.BinarySearch(sValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        MessageBox.Show("The Following Files were found \n" + fValue);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Alerts the user path file doesnt exist
        MessageBox.Show("The File Doesn't Exist!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tzt7yz3.aspx) doesn't mean *partial search*, so that's your first problem. It's trying to match an exact term using the binary search algorithm.

If your list box contains items all of type `String` you can try this instead:

```
fValue = bList.Cast<String>()
    .FirstOrDefault(t =>
                    t.StartsWith(sValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

This will get an `IEnumerable` of type `String` and then locate the first item that starts with the value you have in `sValue`.

EDIT: Since you tagged this ASP .NET you might try this one liner instead. This will get a *collection* of all the matching items and not just the first one as above:

```
var matchingItems = lstbxResults.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(t => t.Text.StartsWith(sValue));
```

Comment: I believe Contains would suit better that StartsWith

Comment: @RenanMalkeStigliani It really depends on how the OP wants to match the term. In the example he indicates that `iexpl` should match `iexplorer.exe`. To me, that's `StartsWith()`.

Comment: @Yuck, If there are multiple item in list box, would i just do a loop ??

Comment: For example if i have 3 different items that start with "ie"  i want to display them all??

Comment: +1. Also using existing autocomplete control or script maybe better approach if it is overall goal.

Comment: @Yuck
Error 1 'System.Windows.Documents.ListItem' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Documents.ListItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Grant Is possible to change the FirstOrDefault to something that would collect all elements that are similar??